# Displaying deeper levels programmatically in a Oracle APEX tree hierarchy

Tags: sql, plsql, tree, oracle-apex

I have a situation where I am going to have a fairly large dataset that I need to represent as a tree hierarchy within Oracle APEX v4.2.2. The dataset might be up to 6000 records with a depth of 5 levels.

Based on another thread, what I am looking at doing and this being the reason of this question, is initially within my tree query, I will only display up to 2 levels, i.e.:

```
WHERE level <= 2
```

My question is, while displaying my tree hierarchy of level <= 2, I want to then allow the user to click on a level 2 node, which would be fed somehow back into my tree hierarchy query and then basically display from a level 2 node down the tree to say the next 2 levels - now displaying from level 2 to level 4 and then continue in the same fashion.

Obviously I will also need a means of getting back to the top level of my tree from any lower levels being displayed at the time - say from level 4.

I am interested in how to best tackle this - I was also thinking whether I display a popup window of the next set of tree hierarchy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 6k records is still manageable by Javascript, so probably the easiest way would be to load the entire tree and collapse it onLoad with a Javascript/JQuery dynamic action.

Otherwise you can also try storing the desired level/key on a Hidden Page Item, build the tree hierarchy query using the value from this page item and just refresh the area with a dynamic action onClick.

Comment: Hi, are you able to elaborate on your second suggestion, specifically with regards to advancing to deeper levels and always using a "between a and b" levels, ie between 0 and 2 then between 2 and 4 then between 4 and 6 and so on until the final levels. Thanks.

Comment: The idea would be to create, in this case, two hidden page items, say P22_MINLEVEL and P22_MAXLEVEL where you're going to store the current levels to be displayed. The tree hierarchy query would include those items with something like

`WHERE level >= :P22_MINLEVEL and level <= :P22_MAXLEVEL`